# Align vertical text from left side

Tags: html, css, position

I have a web page where I want to align my text vertically from the left side which are currently align from the right side.Here is my code in js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r1uoyks6/
I have tried several CSS property like `vertical-align` `text-align` `float:clear`.But failed to achieve the result.I had to `<br/>` to position the `<p>` below one another.Tried `display:inline-block` property but no success.

```css
.taker {
  margin-top: 3em;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.teacher {
  margin-left: 4.0em;
  margin-top: 7em;
  clear: left;
  float: right;
}

.teacher_name {
  margin-left: 4.0em;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="taker">
  <p class="teacher">Submitted To,</p><br/>
  <p style="vertical-align:right;" class="teacher_name">Dr. N M Golam Zakaria</p><br/>
  <p style="vertical-align: right;" class="teacher_name">Professor</p><br/>
  <p style="vertical-align: right;" class="teacher_name">BUET</p><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "vertically from the left side"?

Comment: I think you are trying to align the text *horizontally*, not vertically. So first remove all the `vertical-align` styles because they do nothing. The text is being aligned to the right because of the `float:right` in `.teacher` and `.teacher_name`, so remove those too - there doesn't appear to be any need to float these at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this code and always use text-align property.

```css
.taker {
  margin-top: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.teacher {
  margin-left: 4.0em;
  margin-top: 7em;
  text-align: left;
}

.teacher_name {
  margin-left: 4.0em;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="taker">
  <p class="teacher">Submitted To,</p><br/>

  <p class="teacher_name">Dr. N M Golam Zakaria</p><br/>
  <p class="teacher_name">Professor</p><br/>
  <p class="teacher_name">BUET</p>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no left vertical alignment.

Answer (score 1):

The value `right` doesn't exist for `vertical-align` in CSS. Maybe you meant `text-align`? Otherwise [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) for allowed values of `vertical-align`.

I've removed all floating, positioning and aligning rules from your CSS, so that the text is (per default) left aligned. Is this what you want?

```css
.taker {
  margin-top: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.teacher {
  margin-left: 4.0em;
  margin-top: 7em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.teacher_name {
  margin-left: 4.0em;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="taker">
  <p class="teacher">Submitted To,</p>
  <br/>
  <p class="teacher_name">Dr. N M Golam Zakaria</p>
  <br/>
  <p class="teacher_name">Professor</p>
  <br/>
  <p class="teacher_name">BUET</p>
  <br/>
</div>
```